# Passing Bundle into an AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm struggling with bundles in an AsyncTask. I have two Strings that I want to pass to a AsyncTask, I want to use bundles to accomplish this task.

The code in the MainActivity:

```
Bundle adresses = new Bundle();
adresses.putString("to", textField1.getText().toString());
adresses.putString("from", textField2.getText().toString());

new PriceTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(adresses);
```

And in my AsycTask I do it like this:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Bundle... b) {

   Bundle result = b[0];
   String to = result.getString("to");
   String from = result.getString("from");

}
```

It's worth mentioning that my two strings contains something like this

```
"Sometext here, and sometext here 1234"
```

Put I can't retrieve the text, my debugger says that the Bundle contains the right information but my String will not contain the right information. When I debug and set breakpoints where my Strings are, it will just have the value:

```
[t, o]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your whole code for the Aync Taks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MAin activity replace the below lines::

```
Bundle adresses = new Bundle();
adresses.putString("to", textField1.getText().toString());
adresses.putString("from", textField2.getText().toString());

new PriceTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(adresses);
```

with

```
new PriceTask(getApplicationContext(),textField1.getText().toString(),textField2.getText().toString()).execute();
```

And in your AsycTask add constructor like below::

String to;
String from;
Context context;

public YourAsyncTask(Context context, String to,String from) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this._activity = _activity;
this.to = to;
this.from = from;
    }

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is the way you retrieve the data in the `doInBackground` method. The argument that method having is a Array type. Please concern the **`...`** What you are doing in the line `Bundle result = b[0];` is only getting the 0th element of that Array and pass it to a `Bundle` reference.

Your given code and details is not enough to give a perfect answer. If all your given codes in the same Java class, you no need to use a Bundle. Instead you can create a ArrayList of type String to contains your values witch you are getting from the TextFields. Then doInBackground also contains a ArrayList as the method argument. Then get all the List items and separate your "to" and "from" values.

If you are stick with the existing code, first try to find out what is inside the `result` variable.